# Use Apache To Run SSL On Port 8980 Specifically

Tags: apache, redhat, opennms

I have a web service which I access by typing the following URL exactly as is (character for character):

http://10.115.252.127:8980/opennms/login.jsp

The website files are served from /opt/opennms/jetty-webapps/opennms/

My objective is to use Apache (httpd.conf) to force any traffic to this URL to use SSL and no longer HTTP.

1. I have successfully installed the SSL certificates with no issues.
2. I have configured a VirtualHost directive to redirect port 80 to 443
3. Only sites under /var/www/html/* are being successfully redirected.

Example: http://10.115.252.127/numbers successfully redirects to https://10.115.252.127/numbers
http://10.115.252.127/charts successfully redirects to https://10.115.252.127/charts

But, when I type in the URL http://10.115.252.127:8980/opennms/login.jsp it is always served as HTTP...how do I make it served as HTTPS like the others? I have checked the forums and all the posts assume you will always be redirecting port 80 and dont say anything about how to use SSL in the scenario I explained.  I have the same issue with another service running on port 3000 http://10.115.252.127:3000/login

===extract from my httpd.conf===

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName 10.115.252.127
Redirect permanent / https://10.115.252.127/
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/cert_mtocb2500lbscorp.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/mtocb2500-lbscorp.key
        ServerName 10.115.252.127
        #Documentroot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If you type `http://...`, it defaults to port 80.  If you specify a port (`http://...:8980`) it will do HTTP on port 8980.  So you have to have `Listen 8980` and a `<VirtualHost *:8980>` block in your configuration.

Comment: Hi @Nic3500, thank you for your response.  I have tried what you suggested but unfortunately I get an error when adding `Listen 8980`.  `Apache wont start up and says (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8980`. I tried also to make a symbolic link to `/opt/opennms/jetty-webapps/opennms` but the browser only lists the files and does not execute the login.jsp.  Can you please advise on the exact syntax to put in the `<VirtualHost *:8980>`block?

Comment: I may have misunderstood some details, lets double check.  You currently have HTTP port 80 --redirect--> HTTPS port 443.  That works ok.  Then you have some software (not Apache) that listens on port 8980 right?  And you want to have `https://..../opennms/...` be proxied to that 8980 port.  Did I understand your requirement?

Comment: Hi @Nic3500 apologies for the delayed response, I think we may be on different timezones (I am in South Africa).  You have understood 100% the scenario based on your last comment. 

Apache/Web is not my strength but I have tried various configs in my 8980 virtual tag.  Currently I have it setup like below, but I can never get it to be https://...../opennms/... :(

<VirtualHost *:8980>
<Location /opennms>
      ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8980/opennms
      ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8980/opennms
 </Location>
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your confirmation of my understanding, here is what you can do:

```
############################################################################
Listen 80

# All connections on port 80 are redirected to port 443
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.example.com
    CustomLog "logs/80_access.log" combined
    ErrorLog "logs/80_error.log"

    Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com
    
    # No documentRoot, no content
</VirtualHost>

############################################################################
Listen 443

# All URI are answered from the documentRoot directory
# EXCEPT /openms, which is proxied to :8980
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com

    # temporary, remove when tests done
    LogLevel debug
    CustomLog "logs/443_access.log" combined
    Errorlog "logs/443_error.log"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.crt/cert_mtocb2500lbscorp.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl.key/mtocb2500-lbscorp.key

    # For your redirection to 8980
    ProxyPass           /opennms    "https://www.example.com:8980/"
    ProxyPassReverse    /opennms    "https://www.example.com:8980/"

    documentRoot "/yourdir/apache/htdocs"
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</VirtualHost>
```

Prerequisites

- you must load proxy modules
- you must load rewrite module
- port 8980 is linked to some other software.  Apache does not handle 8980.

Comment: Thank you @Nic3500, this has helped alot.  I am now getting the opennms to redirect to https.  I just need to fix why it is not executing the .jsp pages, but I will treat that as a separate issue.  Appreciate all the patience and assistance on this